# Div in IE6 is not fixing itself on the bottom

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have a div fix on bottom of the page it is working fine in IE7, IE8, FF and chrome. But in IE6 it is not fixing itself on the bottom how can I fix that.

Comment: The title of your question gives the impression your problem is with IE, FF and Chrome. The *body* of the question says they're ok, but IE6 is a mess. This is confusing.

Comment: I think you can ask your question here too -> http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- use a CSS "reset"
- use a CSS framework
- use conditional styles (browser dependent) to work around such problems
- use JavaScript only as a very last resort

More information:

http://www.dezinerfolio.com/2009/02/20/css-standards-best-practices

See also the three links at the end of the **Reset** section.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support `position: fixed` natively. There are some workarounds:

- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html
- http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/